# Cakephp 2.0 mysql query

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I'm new in Cakephp 2.0, but I want to make a view of two tables. I have the following tables:

hpsas with records: ciname, location, status
ldaps with records: ciname, status

In my Controller I have the following syntax:

```
$this->Hpsa->query("SELECT `hpsas`.`ciname`, `hpsas`.`status`, `ldaps`.`ciname`, `ldaps`.`status` FROM `cmdb`.`hpsas`, `cmdb`.`ldaps` WHERE `hpsas`.`ciname` = `ldaps`.`ciname`;");
```

I got the following results as expected:

```
'hpsas' => array(  
    (int) 0 => array(                                  
                  'hpsas' => array(  
            'ciname' => 'lsrv8001',  
            'status' => 'live'  
        ),
        'ldaps' => array(  
            'ciname' => 'lsrv8001',  
            'status' => 'indeployment''
```

How do I make the Model and Controller with the right Cakephp 2.0 syntax?

Comment: This seems way to vague and broad. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to now how to make this query, in Cakephp by using its models and controllers. The result must look like the results as above.

Comment: have you linked your models correctly? With hasMany, belongsTo and hasAndBelongsToMany ?

Comment: Thank you very much xeranas you helped me very good with your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you already done and how your controller/model is named so I just put code samples which may help understand basic idea.

In Hpsas model "many to one" relationship is defined.

```
class Hpsas extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'uniqueAlias1' => array(
            'className'  => 'Ldaps',
            'foreignKey' => 'ciname'
        )
    );
/...
```

In Ldaps model "one to many" relationship is defined.

```
class Ldaps extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'uniqueAlias2' => array(
            'className'  => 'Hpsas',
            'foreignKey' => 'ciname'
        ),
    );
/...
```

Now if perform code `$this->Hpsas->find('all')` on Hpsass controller you will likely get following results:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'uniqueAlias1' => array(
            //hpsas table row with value
        ),
        'uniqueAlias2' => array(
            //ldaps table row where hpsas.ciname = ldaps.ciname 
        )
    ),
        //rest hpsas table rows
)
```

Don't get confused about alias I used in samples, you could named whatever you want. They come handy when need dealing with multiples association for same model.
More detailed explained samples could be found on [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).