# Translate MySQL query into cakephp query

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I would like to translate this $query using the find() method of the cakephp's ORM.

```
$custom_query = $this->Agency->query(
        "SELECT a.id, a.name, a.created, c.total
          FROM agencies a
            join (SELECT agency_id, sum(price) total
                    FROM commands
                    GROUP BY agency_id) C
              on a.id = c.agency_id;"
    );
```

(This query does exactly what I want but I'd like to understand how to use cakephp ORM and $virtualFields)
Thank for your help and your time.

Comment: You need set-up relationships between models fist. See similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12130317/516219).

Comment: No no, I know all that stuff and my relation between models are fine, just need an example with my query with find()

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using CakePHP 1.3 or higher, you can define virtual fields in the model(i.e. calculated fields).

According to your query, I would define the virtual field in the model class like this:

```
$virtualFields = array(
   'total'=>'(SELECT SUM(price) FROM commands WHERE agency_id = Agency.id)'
);
```

Then you can call that field as a regular ORM field:

```
$this->Agency->find('all',array(
    'fields'=>array(
        'id','name','created','total'
        )
    )
);
```

The Cake manual page : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html